# How can I create a symbol of a thick vertical bar that can be inserted into my text?

Tags: tikz-pgf, symbols

How can I insert a symbol of a thick vertical bar into the text? because one of my curves consists of thick vertical bars.

Right now, I am using the following code:

```
The curve consisting of thick, vertical bars $\bm |$ in Fig. 1 shows that ......
```

The result is like

[image]

As you can see from the above picture, the bar in the text is not thick enough, and it is too long.

One of my curves is like (please see the red thick bars in the picture below)

[image]

I want a symbol that can be inserted into texts, and the bar is thicker, shorter. How can I do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SX! You could just use a `\rule`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

The curve consisting of thick, vertical bars \textcolor{red}{\rule{2pt}{0.66em}} in Fig.~1 shows that ...

\end{document}
```

[image]

But if you also want to replicate the other marks in the diagram, you might be better off using Ti*k*Z, I guess (which you added as tag to your question, so you're probably after such a solution anyways):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\thickverticalbar}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
        \draw[line width=2pt, red] (0,0) -- (0,0.66em);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

The curve consisting of thick, vertical bars \thickverticalbar{} in Fig.~1 shows that ...

\end{document}
```

The output looks pretty much the same as that of the other solution.

Comment: You can use the optional argument of \rule to lower the bottom below the baseline (e.g. `\rule[-\dp\strutbox]{2pt}{\baselineskip}`).

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to use `\hstretch{<value>}` of `scalerel` package to create a simple vertical bar very thick.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{oplotsymbl}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\newcommand{\tick}{\raisebox{\depth}{$ \linev $}}
\begin{document}
The curve consisting of thick, vertical bars \textcolor{red}{\hstretch{4}{\tick}} in Fig.~1 shows that \ldots
\end{document}
```

[image]